# Can I change the name of a field in a data structure in Octave?

Tags: data-structures, field, octave

I have a data structure `s` with a field named `f1`.
I want to change the name of the field to `f2`.
Perhaps I could create a new field `f2`, copy all values from `f1` into `f2`, and remove `f1`.
I did not yet completely check all these steps (see below), but ...

**Is there a direct way to change the name of a field in a data structure in Octave?**

**Note**:
Removing a field with [`rmfield`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Manipulating-Structures.html#XREFrmfield) implies creating a copy of the data structure, so it is already more "expensive".

**Useful**:
https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/3383-a-better-way-to-change-the-name-of-a-structure-field

Comment: A long time ago I wrote a `mvfield` function for MATLAB. Never tested in Octave. https://www.crisluengo.net/wp-content/uploads/mvfield.m

Answer (score 3):

You are overthinking this.

Both matlab and octave use [*copy-on-write*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), (specific info on octave [here](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Miscellaneous-Techniques.html)) therefore creating a new field via another field does not cost any memory if none of the two instances change.

```
S1.A = randn(1000,1000);    % 8Mb allocated
S1.B = randn(1000,1000);    % another 8Mb allocated
S1.C = S1.A                 % No allocations. S.C shares memory with S.A

S2 = rmfield(S1, 'A')       % No new allocations. S2 fields share memory with S1 ones.

clear S1                    % total memory allocated at this point: 16Mb
```

Therefore, don't worry about creating extra 'copies' in the way that you describe. It's actually an extremely cheap operation.

Comment: Just to add this comment related to the page linked by OP: `whos` doesn’t help figuring out how much memory is used, if arrays share data it looks like double the amount of memory is used.